# How to generated code from openapi yaml file using openapi-generator-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using "openapi-generator-maven-plugin" to generate code from openapi yaml file and code is getting generated using below configuration but it seems there are some syntax which is wrong.

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openapitools</groupId>
                <artifactId>openapi-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <version>6.6.0</version>
                <!-- /RELEASE_VERSION -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/member_registration.yaml</inputSpec>
                            <generatorName>java</generatorName>
                            <skipValidateSpec>true</skipValidateSpec>
                            <configOptions>
                                <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                                <useTags>true</useTags>
                            </configOptions>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
```

please find following sample error statement.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project swagger-to-code: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/My Data/workspace/poc/swagger-to-code-poc/swagger-to-code/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java/main/org/openapitools/client/model/SearchUsersByUsername200Response.java:[75,35] > expected
[ERROR] /C:/My Data/workspace/poc/swagger-to-code-poc/swagger-to-code/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java/main/org/openapitools/client/model/SearchUsersByUsername200Response.java:[75,36] not a statement
[ERROR] /C:/My Data/workspace/poc/swagger-to-code-poc/swagger-to-code/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java/main/org/openapitools/client/model/SearchUsersByUsername200Response.java:[75,58] not a statement
[ERROR] /C:/My Data/workspace/poc/swagger-to-code-poc/swagger-to-code/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java/main/org/openapitools/client/model/SearchUsersByUsername200Response.java:[75,62] illegal start of expression
[ERROR] /C:/My Data/workspace/poc/swagger-to-code-poc/swagger-to-code/target/generated-sources/openapi/src/gen/java/main/org/openapitools/client/model/SearchUsersByUsername200Response.java:[75,75] not a statement[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Sample Code added.

```
public void write(JsonWriter out, SearchUsersByUsername200Response value) throws IOException {
    if (value == null || value.getActualInstance() == null) {
        elementAdapter.write(out, null);
        return;
    }

    // check if the actual instance is of the type `List&lt;UserSummaryExtended&gt;`
    if (value.getActualInstance() instanceof List&lt;UserSummaryExtended&gt;) {
        JsonObject obj = adapterList&lt;UserSummaryExtended&gt;.toJsonTree((List&lt;UserSummaryExtended&gt;)value.getActualInstance()).getAsJsonObject();
        elementAdapter.write(out, obj);
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: please share SearchUsersByUsername200Response.java and it's yaml definition in openAPI.

Comment: Hi, It's JSON definition in openAPI and following code added.

Comment: json or yaml? (anyways, there roots the problem)

Comment: I can not find JSON definition or any "member_registration.yaml" where schemas is defined.

Answer (score 1):

I used spring instead of java generatorName and it is solved.
Thanks All :)